# Calculate the Frequency of Clamped Bar

Tags: frequency, resonance, vibrations

I'm trying to calculate the resonant frequency of a clamped bar or rather I'm trying to calculate what length of bar to use to get a certain frequency. The goal is to be able to use this to make musical instruments of varying kinds. Tongue drums. Array mbiras. etc.

I found this equation: $ƒ = 0.162 \frac{a}{L^2} \sqrt{\frac {E}{ρ}}$

Which gives me: $L = \sqrt{0.162 \frac{a}{f}\sqrt{\frac {E}{ρ}}}$

I made a spreadsheet to help with the calculation.
[image]

As you can see the calculated length doesn't match the measured length. It's off by a factor of about 5.14. So the question is, why is it off? Did I use the wrong units? The source doesn't seem to mention what units to use so I had to guess.

When I multiply with the 5.14 factor the formula gets pretty close to reality.
[image]

I got the measurements by putting a steel ruler in a vise with varying amounts of stick out (Length) and plucking it with a plectrum until I got all the frequencies I needed.
[image]

Maybe there's a better more accurate equation to use? Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

Source:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Music/barres.html

[image]

Comment: I think your second formula may have been off.

Comment: Can you clarify? Off in what way?

Comment: Not sure. It wasn't very readable, so applied Latex to it.

Comment: You asked: *"Did I use the wrong units?"* Because the constant 0.162 has no stated units it's best to assume you have to use SI units.

Comment: I used Hz, mm, GPa, kg/m^3. Those are all SI units, right? But should I use m or mm? MPa instead of GPa? etc.

Comment: SI specifies $\text{m}$ and $\text{Pa}$, not $\text{GPa}$ or $\text{MPa}$.

Comment: Include in your question one data point, with the units used. Then I'll check it out.

Comment: Ah, your right. It needed to be in meters and Pascals and the solution was in meters as well, of course. That's what confused me. It's still off by a factor of 0.91 but I think I need more complicated formulas to get closer than that. Maybe someone here could help me with that.

Comment: The math for that kind of oscillators is pretty involved, see the example of a simple tuning fork: https://repository.kaust.edu.sa/bitstream/handle/10754/628716/Thesis_final_version.pdf?sequence=3&isAllowed=y

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely look into it. Fascinating stuff.